# if deg(a)=0 in a graph, is "a" counted as an even vertex or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, discrete-optimization, discrete-geometry

i was solving this test, and the answer of title affects the answer, so i was confused.

**Q) in a simple graph, p=10 and 2q/p=3. the graph has 3 isolated vertices and all other vertices have a degree of 5 or 4, how many even vertices does this graph have?**

**1. (5)**
**2. (6)**
**3. (7)**
**4. (8)**

*thank you in advance (:*

Comment: As was indicated in bof's reply to the now-deleted answer, $0$ is an even number, so yes, a vertex with no edges has even degree.